# Parse Json String in php get value from array

Tags: php, json

```
{
    "DeviceTicketInfo ": {
        "UserId ": 27,
        "Ticket ": 18005956,
        "DevInfo ": "sunsoft-123456 "
    },
    "AvailableStations ": [{
        "Id ": 2,
        "No ": 2,
        "Name ": "01-SUNSOFT "
    }]
}
```

I want to echo only the `UserId` from the above `json` string in `php`.

Please help

Comment: `echo json_decode($input, true)['DeviceTicketInfo ']['UserId '];`

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any `json` formatted strings, or array, you can simply use the `json_encode`/`json_decode` PHP built-in functions.

To decode that json just do something the `json_decode()` function:

```
$jsonString = '{
    "DeviceTicketInfo ": {
        "UserId ": 27,
        "Ticket ": 18005956,
        "DevInfo ": "sunsoft-123456 "
    },
    "AvailableStations ": [{
        "Id ": 2,
        "No ": 2,
        "Name ": "01-SUNSOFT "
    }]
}';

$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

This will return a 2-d array with `key`=>`value` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the `json` `string` into a `PHP object` before accessing its properties, [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is your friend here, i.e.:

```
$_json = '{ "DeviceTicketInfo":{ "UserId":27, "Ticket ":18005956, "DevInfo ": "sunsoft-123456 "}, "AvailableStations ":[{ "Id ":2, "No ":2, "Name ": "01-SUNSOFT "}]}';
$_json = json_decode($_json);
print_r($_json->DeviceTicketInfo->UserId);
# 27
```

---

You can also use `true` as 2nd argument in `json_decode($_json, true);` to converted the returned `object` into an associative `array`, then you can access the elements using:

```
$_json['DeviceTicketInfo']['UserId'];
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/GFRdEV)